# Automating REST API calls chaining

Tags: rest, api

I am thinking about creating a service that would automate the process of chaining REST API calls, for example:

1. `POST /jobs` to service A to ask it to process a job.
2. When I get a response for that job, then call `POST /jobs` to service B where some of the data passed in the request body may be mapped from some data we got in service A's response.
3. When I get a response from service B, then ...

What does not seem that easy to me is to create that service without strong coupling between it and the other services: it should not have to know anything about service A or service B except probably a description of the services interfaces with any IDL. Is there any tool or protocols or something that would allow me to describe such execution flows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually this is called an orchestrator.  Netflix has one here:

https://github.com/Netflix/conductor

Here are some details...

[https://en.paradigmadigital.com/dev/conductor-newest-thing-netflix-orchestration-microservices](https://en.paradigmadigital.com/dev/conductor-newest-thing-netflix-orchestration-microservices/)

Not sure if you need that much complexity.  One could just write an implementation of orchestrator service if the needs are not that complex.